# Adding an image to a pane

Tags: java, image

I'm having a little trouble in adding an image to one of my panes? Here is what I am doing:

```
final ImageView imv = new ImageView();
final Image image2 = new Image(Game.class.getResourceAsStream("bg.png"));
imv.setImage(image2);
_gamePane.getChildren().add(imv);
```

Comment: Make sure that `bg.png` resides within the same package as the class which is trying to load it

Comment: what is your file structure? what is the name of the current class? where is bg.png?